# Save input value

Tags: javascript

Ok I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/RaWF7/

When I click on Save I want my `saveFunction` to save the value that is inside the input.

```
function saveFunction(){
    calculator.result.value
 }
```

I know i am going to feel stupid after this:)

```
<li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" onClick="saveFunction()">Edit</a></li>
```

Comment: Where you need to save this value?

Comment: i need it saved... so i can use ctrl+v to display it on another page... i will need the function to work like ctrl+c

Comment: Do you want to save to clipboard? This is not possible with only JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: yes... well wif not javascript what can i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the value within the clipboard you can use this library: https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Currently because if security issues the manipulation of the clipboard using JavaScript is not allowed (at least it's not cross-browser).